# Java synchronize statement around a lock

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

I was wondering if

```
synchronize (lock) {
    ... 
}
```

Where lock is an instance of `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock`, treats  `lock` like any other object or as the try-finally idiom i.e.

```
 lock.lock(); 
 try {
     ... 
 } finally { 
    lock.unlock();
 }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Lock documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html):

> Note that Lock instances are just
>   normal objects and can themselves be
>   used as the target in a synchronized
>   statement. Acquiring the monitor lock
>   of a Lock instance has no specified
>   relationship with invoking any of the
>   lock() methods of that instance. It is
>   recommended that to avoid confusion
>   you never use Lock  instances in this
>   way, except within their own
>   implementation.

So basically, it's treated as any other object.  And, don't do that.

Comment: @hhafez: "Don't do that" because the documentation says "It is recommended that to avoid confusion you never use Lock instances in this way, except within their own implementation."

Answer (score 3):

It will treat the lock just like any other object.

Answer (score -1):

The lock statement in the C# programming language can be applied to restrict access to a specific part of code to only one thread at a time.

Comment: This is a Java question, not a C# question. (I did not vote down.)